# Query M:N relationship with GORM for entity instances _not_ in relation to each other?

Tags: hibernate, grails, hql

I need to track a M:N relationship with attributes, so I'm using a link table (following the pattern at [Many-to-Many Mapping without Hibernate XML](http://www.grails.org/Many-to-Many+Mapping+without+Hibernate+XML)) ... but, I can't see how to query that Membership relationship for legal-but-don't-yet-exist relationships, e.g., any Employees **not** in a given Team (or Items which a User hasn't yet bid on, etc). I'm working on it in HQL, but I'm a noob to that so I could use some guidance on what technique works best ... or, examples of this sort of query ;)

For discussion, just assume the Employees:Team Membership class, with a very large set of each (too large to just pull into the mid-tier and do set operations).

```
class Membership {
    Employee employee
    Team team
    String other // I need attributes on the relationship
}

class Employee {
    Date dateJoinedCompany
    String name
    static hasMany = [managedTeams:Team, memberships:Membership]
    static mappedBy = [managedTeams:"manager"]
}

class Team {
    String name
    Employee manager
    static belongsTo = Employee
    static hasMany = [memberships:Membership]
}
```

So, I need a query which returns Employees not on Team #2 who jined the company more than a month ago, or Teams which Employee #5 is not part of, that sort of thing What's the best technique - is there a way to do this with Criteria? Or, any suggestions on how to best use HQL for it?

I should add my current thought, using HQL and a subselect:

```
from Team t where t not in (select m.team from Membership m where m.employee = 5)
```

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

Employees not on Team #2 who jined the company more than a month ago:

```
Employee.executeQuery("select e from Employee as e inner join e.memberships as m where m.team.id != :tId and e.dateJoinedCompany > :date", [tId: 2, date: new Date() - 60]
//calculate the exact date. instead of using the team id you can use the team instance
```

Teams which Employee #5 is not part of

```
Team.exccuteQuery("select t from Team as t inner join t.memberships as m where m.e.id != :eId",[eId: 5])
```

Comment: Would using an inner join on memberships cause these queries to omit entities who aren't listed in the membership table - e.g., employees who joined more than a month ago but aren't yet in *any* membership?

Comment: then replace the inner join with a left join

Comment: Just to keep you apprised: I haven't dropped this or forgotten to accept the answer ... but (dangers of newbies!) I can't yet get the outer join to work. In my actual app I have Audio, UserCallFlow, and Hearing objects (users in a UCF listen to Audios, and these are are linked through the Hearing table which has 'audi' and 'ucf' fields). The subselect 'Audio aud not in (select h.audio from Hearing h where h.ucf = :ucf' is working, but using 'from Audio aud left join aud.hearings h where h.ucf != :ucf' always returns an empty set. So, still hacking!

Comment: keep on trying. you can activate the hibernate sql logging to see the outcoming sql statements.